# C# printing page height according to the content

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, thermal-printer

I'm doing some printing work in c# and got a small problem. I'm working with a thermal receipt printer. I want to set the height of the page according to the content of it. Which means, when I have fewer items, the page should be smaller and when I have  long list of items, the page should grow accordingly. 
I tried to set it with `PrintPageEventArgs` but this didn't result in satisfied result. How can this be done?

Thanks

Comment: You want to save your paper, don't you? I don't think you can do this, although you can change the paper size setting in `PrinterSettings` but there are only supported paper sizes there.

Answer (score 0):

Just take care of the width. Printer will cut the paper after the last printed element on the last page.

Comment: oh is it? Thanks. Gonna try it

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record. I had the same issue.
At the end what i had done is:

```
Int Line= starting position (in pixels)
For each line I want to print -> g.DrawString("text",font,xx,margin,line);

and then just before print
  ps.Height = Line;
  pd.Print();

pd is ->  PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
ps is ->  PaperSize ps = new PaperSize("",my_width,1));
`enter code here`           pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pd_PrintPage);
            pd.PrintController = new StandardPrintController();
            pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left = 0;
            pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right = 0;
            pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top = 0;
            pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Bottom = 0;
            pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = ps;
```